# Migrating facebook authentication to OAuth 2.0 protocol using symfony plugin

Tags: facebook-graph-api, symfony-1.4, oauth-2.0

Long story short I got involved with a company that had contracted out to have their site built using the symfony framework. They built a custom plugin for facebook authentication. Since Facebook introduced their new authentication protocol I am set with the task of migrating the code for the plugin to use OAuth 2.0. Problem is I am not well versed in PHP and know enough about symfony to get started. What would help me identify what needs changed in order to meet the new protocol standards for facebook authentication so that that function is restored on the company site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only plugin that has out of the box support for OAuth in Symfony 1.X is sfMelody. The documentation is a little sparse, but it definitely works. sfFacebookConnect no longer works and doesn't support OAuth.

Comment: See sfFacebookMelody (OAuth 2)

Comment: I think you mean sfMelody, which is a little flaky with some Facebook features. https://github.com/chok/sfMelodyPlugin

Answer (score 0):

Here's two choices that you can use

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

and

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

Please read thru the documentation on both and see if either fits your needs.

If you must integrate with PHP, there's some good examples of that here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a **custom** plugin for facebook authentication, it's hard to advice anything without code samples.
I guess it must be something like `plugins/sfFacebookUserPlugin/sfFacebookUser.class.php`.

Any case you have to figure out where current plugin retrieves user's ID, and write own implementation using OAuth 2.0, keeping rest of the class functionality unchanged.